Pandas apply with "expand result" results in NaN columns when using loc but not [ ]
I am having some issues around setting new column values that are produced by a pandas apply function. If you scroll to the bottom I've provided a MRE you should be able to copy-paste and run.
Explanation
Let's assume we have a DataFrame df as follows:
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":["ABC", "DEF", "GHI"], "b":[1, 2, 3]})




a
b




ABC
1


DEF
2


GHI
3



The specific data is irrelevant. Let's assume I have another function some_function() that operates on both columns, performs some logic, and returns a tuple of two values that I wish to make into columns.
The logic inside some_function() is irrelevant again, in this example it appends the value of b to an upper and lowercase a value.
def some_func(param_a: str, param_b: int) -> tuple[str, str]:
    output_a = param_a + " " + str(param_b)
    output_b = param_a.lower() + " " + str(param_b)

    return output_a, output_b

If you use [] indexing to insert the columns, then you get:
df[["output_a", "output_b"]] = df.apply(
    lambda row: 
        some_func(row["a"], row["b"]),
    axis=1,
    result_type="expand"
    )

Which results in print(df) giving this (the desired output):



a
b
output_a
output_b




ABC
1
ABC 1
abc 1


DEF
2
DEF 2
def 2


GHI
3
GHI 3
ghi 3



However, if you use the .loc operator instead like so:
df.loc[:, ["output_a", "output_b"]] = df.apply(
    lambda row: 
    some_func(row["a"], row["b"]), 
    axis=1, 
    result_type="expand"
    )

Then print(df) gives:



a
b
output_a
output_b




ABC
1
nan
nan


DEF
2
nan
nan


GHI
3
nan
nan



Question
Is this behaviour expected, or is this a bug? Alternatively, is there something that I am doing wrong?
MRE
You should be able to copy this and run it locally. You will need pandas==2.2.1.
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a":["ABC", "DEF", "GHI"], "b":[1, 2, 3]})
df2 = df.copy()

def some_func(param_a: str, param_b: int) -> tuple[str, str]:
    output_a = param_a + " " + str(param_b)
    output_b = param_a.lower() + " " + str(param_b)

    return output_a, output_b


df[["output_a", "output_b"]] = df.apply(lambda row: some_func(row["a"], row["b"]), axis=1, result_type="expand")

df2.loc[:, ["output_a", "output_b"]] = df.apply(lambda row: some_func(row["a"], row["b"]), axis=1, result_type="expand")

print("DF 1 with [ ]")
print(df)
print()
print("DF 2 with .loc")
print(df2)

Has anyone experienced this issue before, or has some way around it? Alternatively, what is the correct way of accomplishing what I want to accomplish?

Have a look at this post. Basically, your df.loc expects the column labels to match as well, but they don't. E.g., chain .rename(columns={0:'output_a'}) and print that again, you'll find that output_a has been filled.

@ouroboros1 thanks so much. That's exactly it. I'll add an answer to the question and mark it as accepted (unless you want to do that).

Glad to be of help. Sure, go ahead and add an answer :). Good luck with your project
